# Adapting tensorflow LSTM code for binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, lstm

I’m trying to take this basic LSTM model (https://github.com/suriyadeepan/rnn-from-scratch/blob/master/lstm.py), which is a many-to-many sequence model, and convert it into a sequence classifier with a binary outcome.

My outcome and features look like the following:

```
# Features: 
array([[62, 91, 57, ..., 91, 43, 87],
       [66, 20, 52, ..., 91, 33, 20],
       [66, 45, 52, ..., 70, 91, 66],
       ...,
       [72, 20, 20, ..., 17, 14, 66],
       [91, 25, 52, ..., 52, 14, 52],
       [72, 29, 66, ..., 21, 20, 52]], dtype=int32)

# Feature matrix shape
(118929, 20)


# Outcome 
array([[1],
       [0],
       [1],
       ...,
       [0],
       [1],
       [1]])

# Outcome shape
(118929, 1)
```

The modified code looks like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import random
import argparse
import sys

from random import sample
import configparser
import os

import csv
import pickle as pkl

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelBinarizer, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification


def rand_batch_gen(x, y, batch_size):
    while True:
        sample_idx = sample(list(np.arange(len(x))), batch_size)
        yield x[sample_idx], y[sample_idx]



with open('data/paulg/metadata.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    metadata = pkl.load(f)
# read numpy arrays
X = np.load('data/paulg/idx_x.npy')
Y = np.load('data/paulg/idx_y.npy')
idx2w = metadata['idx2ch'] 
w2idx = metadata['ch2idx']


_, Y = make_classification(n_samples = 118929, n_classes = 2, n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=1, n_clusters_per_class=1)
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(Y)
Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)









BATCH_SIZE = 256

class LSTM_rnn():

    def __init__(self, state_size, num_classes,
            ckpt_path='ckpt/lstm1/',
            model_name='lstm1'):

        self.state_size = state_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.ckpt_path = ckpt_path
        self.model_name = model_name

        # build graph ops
        def __graph__():
            tf.reset_default_graph()
            # inputs
            xs_ = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32)
            ys_ = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.int32)

            # embeddings
            embs = tf.get_variable('emb', [100, state_size])
            rnn_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embs, xs_)

            # initial hidden state
            init_state = tf.placeholder(shape=[2, None, state_size], dtype=tf.float32, name='initial_state')
            # initializer
            xav_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer
            # params
            W = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[4, self.state_size, self.state_size], initializer=xav_init())
            U = tf.get_variable('U', shape=[4, self.state_size, self.state_size], initializer=xav_init())
            #b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[self.state_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))

            # step - LSTM
            def step(prev, x):
                # gather previous internal state and output state
                st_1, ct_1 = tf.unstack(prev)

                # GATES
                #
                #  input gate
                i = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,U[0]) + tf.matmul(st_1,W[0]))
                #  forget gate
                f = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,U[1]) + tf.matmul(st_1,W[1]))
                #  output gate
                o = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,U[2]) + tf.matmul(st_1,W[2]))
                #  gate weights
                g = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x,U[3]) + tf.matmul(st_1,W[3]))

                # new internal cell state
                ct = ct_1*f + g*i
                # output state
                st = tf.tanh(ct)*o
                return tf.stack([st, ct])



            states = tf.scan(step, 
                    tf.transpose(rnn_inputs, [1,0,2]),
                    initializer=init_state)

            # predictions
            V = tf.get_variable('V', shape=[state_size, num_classes], 
                                initializer=xav_init())
            bo = tf.get_variable('bo', shape=[num_classes], 
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))


            # get last state before reshape/transpose
            last_state = states[-1]


            # transpose
            states = tf.transpose(states, [1,2,0,3])[0]

            states_reshaped = tf.reshape(states, [-1, state_size])
            logits = tf.matmul(states_reshaped, V) + bo

    # predictions
            predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits) 

            # optimization
            losses = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=ys_)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
            train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)

            # expose symbols
            self.xs_ = xs_
            self.ys_ = ys_
            self.loss = loss
            self.train_op = train_op
            self.predictions = predictions
            self.last_state = last_state
            self.init_state = init_state

        # build graph
        __graph__()


    ####
    # training
    def train(self, train_set, epochs=100):
        # training session
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            train_loss = 0
            try:
                for i in range(epochs):
                    for j in range(100):
                        xs, ys = train_set.__next__()
                        batch_size = xs.shape[0]
                        _, train_loss_ = sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss], feed_dict = {
                                self.xs_ : xs,
                                self.ys_ : ys.flatten(),
                                self.init_state : np.zeros([2, batch_size, self.state_size])
                            })
                        train_loss += train_loss_
                    print('[{}] loss : {}'.format(i,train_loss/100))
                    train_loss = 0
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print('interrupted by user at ' + str(i))

            # training ends here; 
            #  save checkpoint
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            saver.save(sess, self.ckpt_path + self.model_name, global_step=i)







#### main function
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create the model
    model = LSTM_rnn(state_size = 512, num_classes=1)

    # get train set
    train_set = rand_batch_gen(X, Y ,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    # start training
    model.train(train_set)
```

I get the error message:
“Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2).”

Do you know how I can successfully adapt this code for binary classification?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have other bugs. This error comes from `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. In your case, your label should be a vector of length 118929 and logit should be a matrix with a shape (118929, 2). Don't reshape your `Y` from `make_classification` (<strike>`Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)`</strike>).

Comment: Hmm, I still get that error message for some reason.

Comment: @Slyron Which line does this error really refer to? If it's the `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, can you test and show the shape of `logits` and `ys_`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the shape to [None] might help.
`ys_ = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)`